# How to get into a git flow

Tags: git, version-control

I have trouble getting into the habit of using git or source control in general. 
In the beginning of a programming session I am aware that I should commit frequently but after a while I have this coding tunnel vision and forget to commit and then hours later I realize I coded so much that I can't really make useful commits without breaking everything apart which would take a lot of time.

Has anybody some tips and tricks in how a beginner should get into the habit of using a source control system properly.

Comment: Discipline, discipline, discipline.

Comment: You could break up your coding into separate todos you mark on a list or in some tool or whatever. Then, every time you mark off a todo you do a commit.

Comment: I always do it in chunks and committed my code like I don't create todo lists but when I think my task is successfully finished or the file has now proper code I committed it.

Comment: Try going the other way and committing more frequently than you think you'd need to for a while; the beauty of git is that until you've pushed your local branches*, you're free to squash commits together if you later decide you went overboard. *You can still do that it you've pushed, but it can get messy.

Answer (score 1):

Commits are intended to be read. So my advice is: read! Read your own logs and diffs. Read other repositories. Soon you start to distinguish bad code from good code, bad commits from good, bad history from good, clear and understandable from write-only trash.

Then return to your commits. You'll see what's wrong with them and will try to do better commits almost automatically.

Technical hint: use `git add -p` to collect parts of you work and combine them in commits. You don't need to commit everything that was changed at once. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add-patch